Why does the binomial theorem appear in sums of polynomial sequences?
I was recently working on a problem that wanted me to find three functions $f_2(x)$, $f_3(x)$  and $f_4(x)$ such that:
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{n}f_2(r) = n^2 $$
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{n}f_3(r) = n^3 $$
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{n}f_4(r) = n^4 $$
The solutions I worked out were:
$$f_2(x) = 2x -1$$
$$f_3(x) = 3x^2-3x+1$$
$$f_4(x) = 4x^4-6x^2+4x-1$$
The first thing that I immediately realised was that the coefficients were the ones used in binomial expansions. Upon further inspection, I realised I could have gotten to these functions by doing the binomial expansion of $(x-1)^n=0$ then rearranging for $x^n$. I tested this method out for $n=5$:
$$(x-1)^5=x^5-5x^4+10x^3-10x^2+5x-1 = 0$$
$$x^5 = 5x^4-10x^3+10x^2-5x+1$$
$$f_5(x)=5x^4-10x^3+10x^2-5x+1$$
Testing this out using my calculator's summation tool led me to the conclusion:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}f_5(r) = n^5$$
Now I am curious as to why this works, why the binomial theorem shows up in these summations, and whether this method stops working at some point. Any help on this problem would be highly appreciated. Apologies is the answers are very obvious.

Are you familiar with telescoping series?

@Pranay Haven't heard of them.

This question is similar to: Is there a pattern for reducing exponentiation to sigma sums?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. Also, welcome to Math SE.
